# How to redirect a page to another using AngularJS in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, redirect

This is the login page

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
        <!--<script src="controllers/logincontroller"></script> -->     

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

            <title>Login Page</title>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container" ng-controller="loginctrl">
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <label>UserName</label><input class="form-control" ng-model="user.name"><br><br>
        <label>Password</label><input class="form-control" ng-model="user.password"><br><br>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="login()" >Login</button>
        </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/logincontroller.js"></script>
        <script src="angularjs/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
        </body>
        </html>                 

   This is Controller page

        var myapp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

        myapp.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                controller: 'loginctrl',
                templateUrl: 'login.html'
            })
            .when('/addusers', {
                controller: 'addusersctrl',
                templateUrl: 'addusers.html'
            })
            .otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });            
        }]);

        myapp.controller('loginctrl',['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location',function($scope,$http,$location){
            console.log("im a controller");            

            $scope.login = function() {
                //console.log($scope.user);

                // $http.post('/login',$scope.user).success(function(response){
                //  console.log(response);
                // });

                $http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: '/login',
                      data: $scope.user 
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available

                        console.log(response.data);
                        //$window.location.href = 'addusers.html';
                         $location.path("/addusers");
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {

                        console.log(response.data);
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });            
            };
        }]);            

        myapp.controller('addusersctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){
            console.log("im a controller");           

            $scope.login = function() {
                //console.log($scope.user);

                // $http.post('/login',$scope.user).success(function(response){
                //  console.log(response);
                // });

                $http({
                      method: 'post',
                      url: '/login',
                      data: $scope.user 
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                        // this callback will be called asynchronously
                        // when the response is available

                        console.log(response.data);
                        //$window.location.href = 'addusers.html';

                    }, function errorCallback(response) {

                        console.log(response.data);
                        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                        // or server returns response with an error status.
                    });            
            };
        }]);
```

Whenever I am trying to run this code I am getting

> Angular.js error
>       angular.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.1/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.6.1%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A332)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem in [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) (first controller):

```
myapp.controller('loginctrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', 
                 function($scope, $http, $location) {
```

You didn't inject the same things. Change it to:

```
myapp.controller('loginctrl', ['$scope', '$route', '$http', '$routeParams', '$location', 
                 function($scope, $route, $http, $routeParams, $location) {
```